# fetching from database and displaying them in different tags

Tags: html, loops, asp-classic

i have a data base and i have this code which fetch the information from it and display it on a table

```
   <table border="1">
   <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Gender</th><th>City</th></tr>
   <%do until rs.EOF%>
   <tr>
 <%for each x in rs.Fields%>
 <%IF (x.value="ID") THEN%>
 <td><a href="form7.asp?id=1">
 <%Response.Write(x.value)%>
 </td>
 <%ELSE%> 
 <td>
 <%Response.Write(x.value)%><a/>
 </td>
 <%END IF%>

   <%next%>
   </tr>
   <%
   rs.MoveNext
   loop
   %>
   </table>

   <%
   rs.close
   conn.close
   %>
```

this will display all the info as a hyper link what i want is just one of them displayed as a link and the rest suppose to be normal text

for example i want only the id as a link  tag and the rest i want to display it as a normal  tag

how to do that ? can someone help please ?

Comment: if (x.value=="id") ... else ...

Comment: @mplungjan can you check my edited code please .. did you mean like this ? this will print it all as a normal text

Comment: Then x.value is not ="ID" in the case your want.

Comment: @mplungjan ok this is what i want but this is when i want one specific id only .. i want the whole id column to be as a hyper link .. how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is so confusing.

This is what you need.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>City</th>
    </tr>

    <%do until rs.EOF%>
        <tr>
            <%for each x in rs.Fields%>
                <%IF (x.value="ID") THEN%>
                    <td>
                        <a href="form7.asp?id=<%=rs(x.value)%>">
                            <%Response.Write rs(x.value)%>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                <%ELSE%> 
                    <td>
                        <%Response.Write rs(x.value)%>
                    </td>
                <%END IF%>
            <%next%>
        </tr>
    <%
        rs.MoveNext
        loop
    %>
</table>
```

But, if your query returns more fields than your `table head`, your table will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border='1' cellspacing='2' cellpadding='2'>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th align=right>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>City</th>
    </tr>

    <%
    do until rs.EOF
        response.write("<tr>") & vbCrLf

        response.write("<td>")
        response.write("<a href='form7.asp?id=" & rs("ID") & "'>")
        response.Write rs("ID")
        response.Write ("</a>")
        response.Write ("</td>")

        '======================
        'NOTE: I'm breaking these next 4 columns down instead of using your "for" loop
        'REASON: Inevitably you will want to format these differently from each other
        'See the "age" column as an example.
        'Also: easier to understand what is going on
        '======================
        response.write("<td>")
        response.Write rs("Name")
        response.Write ("</td>")

        response.write("<td align=right>")
        response.Write rs("Age")
        response.Write ("</td>")

        response.write("<td>")
        response.Write rs("Gender")
        response.Write ("</td>")

        response.write("<td>")
        response.Write rs("City")
        response.Write ("</td>")

        response.write("</tr>") & vbCrLf

        rs.MoveNext
        loop
        rs.close
        set rs=nothing
    %>
</table>
```